# How can I count and select some rows in a Web table using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'm developing an Automation test using Selenium WebDriver and Java, I need to assured that there are items in the web table, and select one of those items, but the ID is dynamic.

**HTML code:**

```
<table class="datagrid-btable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout: auto;">    <tbody>
      <tr id="datagrid-row-r4-2-0" datagrid-row-index="0" class="datagrid-row datagrid-row-selected">
         <td field="PLANT_CODE" style="display:none;">
            <div style="text-align: left;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-PLANT_CODE">1001</div>
         </td>
         <td field="PLANT_NM">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-PLANT_NM">TESTE1</div>
         </td>
         <td field="PU_NAME" style="display:none;">
            <div style=";text-align:left;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-PU_NAME"></div>
         </td>
         <td field="SUPPLIER_CODE">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-SUPPLIER_CODE">SUP001AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="SUPPLIER_NM">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-SUPPLIER_NM">SUPPLIER 001 AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="ITEM_CODE">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-ITEM_CODE">ITEM001AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="ITEM_NM">
            <div style=";text-align:left;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-ITEM_NM">ITEM1 AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="WRHOUSNG_NO" style="display:none;">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-WRHOUSNG_NO"></div>
         </td>
         <td field="ORDE_NO" style="display:none;">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-ORDE_NO"></div>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="datagrid-row-r4-2-1" datagrid-row-index="1" class="datagrid-row">
         <td field="PLANT_CODE" style="display:none;">
            <div style="text-align: left;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-PLANT_CODE">1001</div>
         </td>
         <td field="PLANT_NM">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-PLANT_NM">BOCAR LERMA</div>
         </td>
         <td field="PU_NAME" style="display:none;">
            <div style=";text-align:left;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-PU_NAME"></div>
         </td>
         <td field="SUPPLIER_CODE">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-SUPPLIER_CODE">SUP001AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="SUPPLIER_NM">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-SUPPLIER_NM">SUPPLIER 001 AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="ITEM_CODE">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-ITEM_CODE">ITEM001AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="ITEM_NM">
            <div style=";text-align:left;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-ITEM_NM">ITEM1 AR</div>
         </td>
         <td field="WRHOUSNG_NO" style="display:none;">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-WRHOUSNG_NO">PUR1</div>
         </td>
         <td field="ORDE_NO" style="display:none;">
            <div style=";text-align:center;" class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c4-ORDE_NO">PUR1</div>
         </td>
      </tr>    </tbody> </table>
```

I tried "**My code**":

```
WebElement tbody = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='datagrid-body']/tbody/tr"));
```

In this case, my request is returning two rows so how can I count the rows and select one of these?
Thanks

Comment: Hi Cleicy, what have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: look at  attribute `datagrid-row-index="0"` increment it gradually and in every row you have specific set of columns which seems static

Comment: Hi @mrfreester :) First of all I tried to select the first row using id/xpath to know if there is results in the table, but I discovered that ID is dynamic so I can't map the element this way. So I tried "My code", but is not working too

Comment: Thanks! Do you care which row you get? You could probably just do `"(//*[@class='datagrid-body']/tbody/tr)[1]"` if you want to grab the 1st one. Or use `findElements` instead and grab the first one from the list. If you want to get a specific one the answer would be more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this step for get you want.

**1. Table initialize**

In your case, the table has the class `datagrid-btable`, the way to initialize it :

```
WebElement tbl = driver.findElement(By.className("datagrid-btable"));
```

**2. Row initialize**

The name tag for the web table row in general is `tr`, the way to initialize it :

```
List<WebElement> rows = tbl.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
```

You can get `rowCount` with :

```
int count = rows.size();
System.out.println("count rows :" +count);
```

**3. Column initialize**

The name tag for the web table column in general are `th` or `td`, the way to initialize it :

`td` tag

```
List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(rowIndex).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
```

**So you can select particular cell by :**

```
String cell = cols.get(indexCol).getText();
```

**Example for select `col1` in `row1` :**

```
List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
String cell = cols.get(0).getText();
System.out.println("cell value :" +cell);
```

Or try this iteration for select all cell table :

```
for(int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++) {
    //check column each in row, identification with 'td' tag
    List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    //column iteration
    for(int j=0; j<cols.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println("row " +(i+1) +" col " +(j+1) +" : " +cols.get(j).getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: @CleicyGuião Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can get count of the rows using `findElements` method:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".datagrid-btable tr.datagrid-row"));
System.out.println(rows.size());
```

Easy way to select row with specific text using [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

```
// get row contains text 1001
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datagrid-btable']//tr[@class='datagrid-row' and contains(.,'1001')]")).click();

// get row by PLANT_CODE and exact cell value
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='datagrid-btable']//tr[@class='datagrid-row' and .//td[@field='PLANT_CODE' and div[text()='1001']]]")).click();
```

To find row you need, you can use `stream().filter()`. In the example below, rows filtered by `PLANT_NM` text. Using filter or rows iteration, you can write a method to filter rows by any/multi cells:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".datagrid-btable tr.datagrid-row"));
System.out.println(rows.size());

List<WebElement> filteredRows = rows.stream().filter(element ->
        element.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[field='PLANT_NM'")).getText().equals("BOCAR LERMA"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Assert.assertTrue(filteredRows.size() > 0, "Row with \"BOCAR LERMA\" PLANT_NM exist.");
filteredRows.get(0).click();
```