# Selecting a specific column value from a specific row - Java Selenium

Tags: selenium, html-table

I have a table with 3 rows (tr's) and 3 columns (td cells).

About this table:

1.The columns are not fixed, and 1st column can be moved to 2nd column.

2.The manager column just contains a round box like img which will be checked (only one at a time).

`Name     Email            Manager`

`Name1    email_id_1       roundbox (selected currently)`

`Name2    email_id_2       roundbox`

`Name3    email_id_3       roundbox`

I was successful in getting the number of rows, number of columns, index of each column from the table.

```
List<WebElement> rows = tablelocator.findElements(By.path of rows locator)
print(rows.size)
```

But the next step is failing where in the element `"Xpath of the selected manager"` is not visible (not time / wait related issue).

```
WebElement rowWhichIWant = driver.findElement(By.xpath("path of row 1 whose manager is selected"));
```

The above fails with `no such element` (even though the row gets highlighted in the browser when searching with this locator, so its not a locator problem as well)

I want to retrieve only the email id of the currently selected manager, i.e `email_id_1`.

HTML:

```
<div tabindex="0" id="somename">
      <table class="x1ns" summary="some summary">
         <colgroup span="3">
            <col style="width:161px;">
            <col style="width: 210px;">
            <col style="width: 310px;">
         </colgroup>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th style="padding:0px;padding-left:11px;width:150px;"></th>
               <th style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 11px; width: 199px;"></th>
               <th style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 11px; width: 299px;"></th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
               <th id="someid">
                  <div style="some style">
                     <table id="some id">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td _afrsortasc="1"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1nw" title="Sort Ascending"></a></td>
                              <td _afrsortdesc="1"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1nx" title="Sort Descending"></a></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x1zr"><span class="af_column_label-text">Name</span></div>
               </th>
               <th id="someid">
                  <div style="some style">
                     <table id="some id">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td _afrsortasc="1"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1nw" title="Sort Ascending"></a></td>
                              <td _afrsortdesc="1"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1nx" title="Sort Descending"></a></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x1zr"><span class="af_column_label-text">E-Mail</span></div>
               </th>          
               <th id="someid">
                  <div style="some style">
                     <table id="some id">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td _afrsortasc="1"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1nw" title="Sort Ascending"></a></td>
                              <td _afrsortdesc="1"><a tabindex="-1" class="x1nx" title="Sort Descending"></a></td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                  </div>
                  <div class="x1zr"><span class="af_column_label-text">Manager</span></div>
               </th>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="some id">
      <table summary="some summary" class="x1nj x1o7">
         <colgroup span="3">
            <col style="width:161px;">
            <col style="width: 210px;">
            <col style="width: 310px;">
         </colgroup>
         <tbody>
            <tr _afrrk="0" class="xep">
               <td style="width: 199px;" class="xeq" nowrap=""><a id="someid1" class="someclass1" href="mailto:email_id_1@email.com">email_id_1@email.com</a></td>
               <td style="width: 299px;" class="xeq" nowrap=""><a id="someid2" class="someclass2" onclick="this.focus();return false;" href="#">Name1</a></td>
               <td style="width:90px;" class="xeq" nowrap="" align="center"><img id="someimgid1" title="Primary" alt="Primary" class="xje"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr _afrrk="1" class="xep">
               <td class="xeq" nowrap=""><a id="someid3" class="someclass3" href="mailto:email_id_2@email.com">email_id_2@email.com</a></td>
               <td class="xeq" nowrap=""><a id="someid4" class="someclass4" onclick="this.focus();return false;" href="#">Name2</a></td>
               <td class="xeq" nowrap="" align="center"><a id="someaid2" title="Primary" class="xko p_AFIconOnly" onclick="this.focus();return false;" href="#"><img id="someimgid2" title="Primary" alt="Primary" class="_afrImageNotLoadedInTime xi8"></a></td>

            </tr>
            <tr _afrrk="2" class="xep">
               <td class="xeq" nowrap=""><a id="someid3" class="someclass3" href="mailto:email_id_3@email.com">email_id_3@email.com</a></td>
               <td class="xeq" nowrap=""><a id="someid4" class="someclass4" onclick="this.focus();return false;" href="#">Name3</a></td>
               <td class="xeq" nowrap="" align="center"><a id="someaid3" title="Primary" class="xko p_AFIconOnly" onclick="this.focus();return false;" href="#"><img id="someimgid3" title="Primary" alt="Primary" class="xi8"></a></td>
            </tr>            
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div id="someid123" style="height: 0px; width: 1040px;"></div>
   <div id="someid234" class="x1ob" style="position:absolute;display:none"></div>
   <div id="someid345" class="x1nk" style="position:absolute;display:none;overflow:hidden"></div>
   <div id="someid456" style="display:none"></div>
   <div tabindex="-1" id="someid567" style="position: absolute; overflow: auto; z-index: 0; width: 1040px; top: 33px; height: 261px; right: 0px;">
      <div style="width: 1040px; height: 223px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code

Comment: Provided HTML in edit. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

`no such element` indicates that indeed the element was not found, You can try this code to get all the text from the table :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'x1nj')]")));
WebElement tbl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'x1nj')]"));
List<WebElement> rows = tbl.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int i=0; i<rows.size(); i++) {
    //check column each in row, identification with 'td' tag
    List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(i).findElements(By.tagName("td"));

    //column iteration
    for(int j=0; j<cols.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println("row " +(i+1) +" col " +(j+1) +" : " +cols.get(j).getText());
    }
}
```

Console output :

[image: console output]

So this is to get the cell you want :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'x1nj')]")));
WebElement tbl = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'x1nj')]"));
List<WebElement> rows = tbl.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
List<WebElement> cols = rows.get(0).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
WebElement cell1 = cols.get(0);
WebElement cell2 = cols.get(1);
System.out.println("get text : " +cell1.getText());
System.out.println("get text : " +cell2.getText());
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467583/how-can-i-count-and-select-some-rows-in-a-web-table-using-selenium/57471481#57471481)

Comment: Thanks Frian. But my question is a bit different.

Comment: As per your code, after clicking the cellYouWant, how do I get the text from it's corresponding column (i.e name or email id)